# Can i switch a SSHD with an HDD in lenovo z50-75?

Tags: hard-drive

Can I switch a SSHD with a HDD in Lenovo z50-75?
I want to backup some data from an HDD drive and I plan on using a bootable USB recovery tool but I have no idea whether my motherboard will say no.

Comment: Can you post specifics like SSHD model and current HDD model?

Comment: Normally a painless operation, I have seen many Lenovo T4xx upgraded that way, as well at two MacBookPros. The only thing to check to check is the physical thickness of the SDD compared to the HDD bay, If the HDD is a 9mm and the SSD a 7mm you'll have to find some physical adapter to hold the SSD. If the bay is only meant for 7mm HDD then a 9mm SSD won't fit, but AFAIK all SSDs are 7mm.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem as long as the hard drive is the same size physically.

Comment: did it. works like a charm!